# BeautifulSoup4 find all non nested matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, recursive-datastructures

I am in trouble for setting up a simple search of all **outermost** elements matching my query in an html document. I ask here with the hope that there is a simple `bs4` function that does this, but it doesn't appear so.

Consider the following html example, where I want all outermost `<div>` that have the `"wanted"` class (I expect to get a list of **2**):

```
import bs4

text = """
<div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="wanted">
            I want this.
            <div class="wanted">
                I don't want that!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="wanted">
            I want this too.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')

# 1. Trying all at once
fetched = soup.findAll('div', class_='wanted')
print(len(fetched))  # 3

fetched = soup.findAll('div', class_='wanted', recursive=False)
print(len(fetched))  # 0

fetched = soup.findChildren('div', class_='wanted')
print(len(fetched))  # 3

fetched = soup.findChildren('div', class_='wanted', recursive=False)
print(len(fetched))  # 0


# 2. Trying one after the other
fetched = []
fetched0 = soup.find('div', class_='wanted')

while fetched0:
    fetched.append(fetched0)
    descendants = list(fetched0.descendants)
    fetched0 = descendants[-1].findNext('div', class_='wanted')

print(len(fetched))  # 2  Hurra!

# 3. Destructive method: if you don't care about the parents of this element
fetched = []
fetched0 = soup.find('div', class_='wanted')
while fetched0:
    fetched.append(fetched0.extract())
    fetched0 = soup.find('div', class_='wanted')
print(len(fetched))
```

So nothing in the part `# 1.` gives the expected result. Therefore what's the difference between `findAll` and `findChildren` ?? And `findNextSibling` is not relevant given the nesting here.

Now, part `# 2.` works, but why the need to write so much code? Isn't there a more elegant solution? As for part `# 3.`, one must be careful of the consequences I guess.

What are your suggestions about this search? Did I really find the shortest way? Is there some CSS select magic I could use?

Comment: If you don't want to match inner divs, you can try `divs = [div for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='wanted') if not div.findParent('div', class_='wanted')]`. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that would give what I want. However, I thought there would be a method to avoid going into the substructure at all.

Comment: You can try CSS selector that will match the child of `<div class="inner">` if it suites you: `soup.select('.inner > .wanted')`

Answer (score 1):

you could pass in a function as argument to `find_all`, in addition to other arguments. And inside it you could check with find_parents() to make sure it does not have a any top-level div with the same class. Use `find_parents()` as it will check for all parents not just its immediate parent, so that you get only the outermost 'wanted' div.

```
def top_most_wanted(tag):
    children_same_class=tag.find_parents("div", class_="wanted")
    if len(children_same_class) >0:
        return False
    return True
soup=BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all(top_most_wanted,'div',class_="wanted"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did the following, which has the advantage of not being destructive. Also, I don't have time to benchmark it, but I was just hoping that this would avoid going through each nested elements as in @Bitto-Bennichan answer, but really this is unsure. Anyway it does what I wanted:

```
all_fetched = []
fetched = soup.find('div', class_='wanted')

while fetched is not None:
    all_fetched.append(fetched)
    try:
        last = list(fetched.descendants)[-1]
    except IndexError:
        break
    fetched = last.findNext('div', class_='wanted')
```